# SetState Not Working After GraphQL Mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, react-hooks

If the mutation is successful, I am trying to `setAdded` to `true` in the .then of ```submitForm()``. If this is true, I want to show a message from the SuccessfulMessage(). However, when I log the value of added, I keep seeing false.

Since `added`is not changed to true. I am unable to see any message when mutation is successful. Why doesn't it change?

```
export default function AddUserPage() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    phoneNumber:'',
    loggedIn: false,
  });  

  const [added, setAdded] = useState(false);

  function SuccessMessage(){
    if (added)
    {
      console.log('User Added');
      return (
      <Typography>
        User Added
        </Typography>)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(added){
      SuccessMessage();
    }
  },[] );

function submitForm(AddUserMutation: any) {
    const { firstName, lastName, email, password, phoneNumber } = state;
    if (firstName && lastName && email && password && phoneNumber) {
      AddUserMutation({
        variables: {
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName,
          email: email,
          password: password,
          phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        },
      }).then(({ data }: any) => {
        setAdded(true);
        console.log('doing', added);
        console.log('ID: ', data.createUser.id);
        console.log('doing', added);
      })
        .catch(console.log)
    }
  }

  return (
    <Mutation mutation={AddUserMutation}>
      {(AddUserMutation: any) => (
        <div>
          <PermanentDrawerLeft></PermanentDrawerLeft>
          <Formik
            initialValues={{ firstName: '', lastName: '', email: '', password: '', phoneNumber: '' }}
            onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                actions.setSubmitting(false);
              }, 1000);
            }}
            validationSchema={schema}
          >
            {props => {
              const {
                values: { firstName, lastName, email, password, phoneNumber },
                errors,
                touched,
                handleChange,
                isValid,
                setFieldTouched
              } = props;
              const change = (name: string, e: any) => {
                e.persist();
                handleChange(e);
                setFieldTouched(name, true, false);
                setState( prevState  => ({ ...prevState,   [name]: e.target.value })); 
              };
              return (
                <div className='main-content'>
                  <form style={{ width: '100%' }} 
                  onSubmit={e => {e.preventDefault();
                    submitForm(AddUserMutation);SuccessMessage()}}>
                    <div>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        id="firstName"
                        name="firstName"
                        helperText={touched.firstName ? errors.firstName : ""}
                        error={touched.firstName && Boolean(errors.firstName)}
                        label="First Name"
                        value={firstName}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, "firstName")}
                      />
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        id="email"
                        name="email"
                        helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ""}
                        error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                        label="Email"
                        value={email}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, "email")}
                      />
                      <Button
                      type="submit"
                      disabled={!isValid || !email || !password}
                      >
                        Add User</Button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              )
            }}
          </Formik>
        </div>
      )
      }
    </Mutation>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you are already using hooks, why aren't you just using the [`useMutation`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#executing-a-mutation) hook too?

Comment: If you add a console.log() after the setAdded(true) line, does it show?

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to use that according to my code actually. Could you help? @trixn

Comment: Nope, it doesn't show. It keeps saying false. That's the problem @rrd

Answer (score 1):

Your `console.log()` directly after calling `setAdded` will not show `true` as state updates are async an will only be visible on the next render. Also your `SuccessMessage` will never be triggered because you did not provide any dependencies for your `useEffect()`. This means it will only ever be called after mount

You need to add `added` to the dependency list:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(added){
        SuccessMessage();
    }
},[added]);
```

But actually I don't see any reason to trigger it in a `useEffect` anyways. Why not just call it in the mutation handler?

Also if you are already using hooks you can use [`useMutation`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#executing-a-mutation).

Also you can't return JSX from a handler. It will not do anything. How should react even know where to display your `<Typography>User Added</Typography>`? You must render everything in the component itself depending on the state.

Comment: I did this. It prints the 'User Added' message to console now. From the SuccessMessage() function but still doesn't return the error message i.e typography

Comment: @a125 This is not how react works. You can't return JSX in a handler. How should react even know where to render this? Everything that you want to render has to be returned by a component. Changing what gets rendered works by changing the state which will trigger a re-render.

Comment: Adding ```{added && SuccessMessage()}```at the end of the form worked. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

## Sorry, but ...

**... it looks like a great example of abusing react ... result of skipping basic tutorials, docs and mixing random oudated examples**.

- async nature of `useState` (and `setState`) - you can't expect updated value;
- using `useEffect` param without knowledge how it affects behaviour;
- 'useEffect' not required at all;
- returning components from event handler instead of [data driven] conditional rendering;
- if `useMutation` used you don't need to pass mutation as param to event handler;
- you're using Formik (with fields validation) then checking params (fields) in handler is simply unnecessary;
- you can simply use `variables: { ...state }` if variables props names are matching;
- **Formik manages values, you don't need to duplicate this using local state** - any reason?;
- Formik has hooks, too ;) use `useFormik()`;
- ... event handlers, binding...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I am trying to modify my code accordingly step by step. Could you please have a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60789766/change-formik-to-useformik